# Malloc'ed memory returned by function is not being freed

Tags: c, malloc, free

Below I am using function **input** to collect and return a string to function **main**.
I stored the returned pointer/string in a char* and am using that variable to free the malloced memory after using it.

However, it appears that the malloced memory is still usable after my **free** call.

```
char* input();
const int MAX = 100;

int main() {
    while(1) {
        char * input_function_pointer = input();

        printf("%p", &input_function_pointer);
        puts(input_function_pointer);   
        
        free(input_function_pointer);
        puts("_______");

        printf("%p", &input_function_pointer);
        puts(input_function_pointer); 
        puts("_______");
    }
return 0;
}

char* input() {
   char * str = malloc(MAX);
   printf( "Enter a value :");
   fgets( str, MAX, stdin );
return str;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior

Comment: Basically, you're using your hotel room key after you checked out.  What you left in the room may be there, or it may not be there.

Comment: @dbush And you might be in your hotel room when the demolition charges reduce it to rubble...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freeing memory does not enforce erasing its content (depends on compiler option, mostly debugging turned on) and nothing prevents you from accessing that space. You're in Undefined Behavior accessing what is called a "dangling pointer": you will probably still see the same content right after you've freed it, probably not after other malloc are called ... or crash.

Freeing memory is merely marking that space as available for allocation, not preventing further read (or write) access. That's (also) why C is considered "low level".

Comment: *Freeing memory doesn't erase its content*  Oh?  Try using a debug C runtime library...

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's right, I edited to make it clearer it *can* happen under some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

There are no guarantees what will happen if you try to access a chunk of memory after `free`ing it. This is undefined behavior, which just happens to work in this case, with your specific compiler.

Comment: @seamus: "freed" doesn't mean "emptied".

Comment: @seamus No. The memory you accessed after you freed it still existed and still contained what it held before you freed it.  Neither of which is a safe assumption.  It's up to **YOU** to not write code that depends on behavior like that.

Answer (score 2):

7.22.3.3 The free function [c11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
> deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation

Dereferencing [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)  invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`free` does not amend the content of the freed memory. It does not also change the pointer.

The pointer containing the reference to the freed memory is called **`dangling pointer`** and dereferencing it (as you do in your program) is an Undefined Behaviour